use FormControl on HTML string returned from an API
I have an API that returns a large HTML string with many inputs, text areas, checkboxes, each named with ids and other metadata.
I am currently rendering this HTML into my page with [innerHtml]="sanitizedHtmlString", and interacting with the inputs via TypeScript DOM manipulation. Is there a clever way to create reactive form controls on top of this HTML so that I can work with form controls and Angular libraries instead?

Probably people are hesitant to add an answer because it's hard to proof it. But I'm pretty sure this not possible, because with the innerHTML you cannot use the directive necessary for reactive forms.

I was thinking my last resort is I can use fromEvent(input, 'input').pipe(...), and capture all changes on all inputs, which is a step up from doing input.addEventListener, but feels a bit like reinventing the wheel.
